# Linked-Server with distributed Transaction: Not possible to read data

Tags: sql-server, oracle

we're sending data from a Oracle-Server to a SQL-Server.
What I would like to do on the SQL-Side: I'd like to select data, which was inserted on the Oracle-side, to make some Insert/Update checks.

So a example:

On Oracle side I insert a value on the Table LANG_PARAM:

```
insert into lang_param
values p_rec
;
```

On the SQL-Server side, I try to read out the data and fill it in a parameter:

```
  SELECT      @Id = LANG_PARAM_ID
  FROM        LANG_PARAM
  WHERE       LANG_PARAM_ID = @lang_Param_Id
```

But I always get null back. Since I didn't find anything about this case, it is just not possible or do I need to set something?

P.S. I cutted the Linked-Server name at the select ,but it'd be there.

Thanks in advance and a good start in the week.

Matthias

Comment: Did you commit the insert in Oracle before trying the select in SQL Server?

Comment: And what datatype is your LANG_PARAM_ID column? We have had issues that if a column in Oracle is simply `NUMBER` without any precision/scale, then SQL Server will try converting to string as it cannot know for certain what `NUMERIC` datatype it needs to use. Try maybe in SQL Server to create a view as `select * from LANG_PARAM` (including the linked server name of course) and then see in SQL Server which datatypes the columns of that view got.

Comment: As far as I know I dont have to commit the transaction to get the data as long as I am in the same transaction? Or am I wrong there?

Comment: Then I probably don't understand your setup. By distributed transaction do you mean Oracle XA (X/Open)? How does the code that inserts in Oracle know that it is part of the same transaction as the select in SQL Server? Is the insert actually performed from the SQL server on the same connection as the select? Or have you started a global transaction with a transaction manager and specified that same global transaction both in your Oracle connection and your SQL Server connection? I am afraid a little more detail is needed ;-)